# Add a member using python requests and Mailchimp API v3

Tags: python, python-requests, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to learn more about using http requests and the Mailchimp API, but I cannot seem to figure out how to add a member to list using a post request.  I have tried multiple configurations, and I guess I made some headway since my response went from a 405, to a 401, now I'm getting a 400.  I assume this means that I am being authenticated, but I am formatting the request incorrectly.

I have gotten it to work the python mailchimp library, but I want to actually learn how to use the HTTP requests.  I could find very few examples of using python requests with Mailchimp.

(obviously I put in my actual list_id, my_username, and my_apikey)

```
import requests, json


members_url = 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXXXXXX/members/'
auth = ('my_username', 'my_apikey')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


data1 = {
    'email_address':'blah@blah.com',
    'status':'subscribed',
    'merge_fields':{
        'FNAME':'John',
        'LNAME':'Doe'
        }
    }

payload = json.dumps(data1)

response = requests.post(members_url, auth=auth, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

This is my response:

```
>>> response
<Response [400]>
```

I'm stumped....what am I doing wrong?

This worked:

```
import requests, json


members_url = 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXXXXXX/members/'
auth = ('my_username', 'my_apikey')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


data1 = {
    'email_address':'<a real email address>',  #it could tell 'blah@blah.com was fake'
    'status':'subscribed',
    'merge_fields':{
        'FNAME':'John',
        'LNAME':'Doe'
        }
    }

response = requests.post(members_url, auth=auth, headers=headers, json=data1)
```

Comment: Check the response content `response.content` to see whether the error message explains the problem.

Comment: You are json encoding the data twice. Use `requests.post(..., data=json.dumps(data1))` or `requests.post(..., json=data1)`.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, you pointed me in the right direction.   I checked response.content and it said `...Schema describes object, string found instead` due to double encoding the json data.  I fixed it (which I had previously tried both ways) and it said `blah@blah.com looks fake or invalid, please enter a real email address.","instance`, which is why I couldn't get it to work either way.  I put in a real address and it works now.  Thanks again...another learning experience.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Please add you solution as an answer, instead of updating the question. It makes it easier to see that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
import requests, json


members_url = 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXXXXXX/members/'
auth = ('my_username', 'my_apikey')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


data1 = {
    'email_address':'<a real email address>',  #it could tell 'blah@blah.com was fake'
    'status':'subscribed',
    'merge_fields':{
        'FNAME':'John',
        'LNAME':'Doe'
        }
    }

response = requests.post(members_url, auth=auth, headers=headers, json=data1)
```

My problems were #1 I was double encoding the json data and #2 mailchimp recognizes obviously BS email addresses like blah@blah.com

Thanks @Alasdair